# Proper "Scope" setup for manifest. Not working as expected

Tags: routes, single-page-application, manifest, progressive-web-apps

For my pwa I am having issue where the manifest.json gets called on the end of whatever page I'm on like `mydomain.com/subpage/manifest.json` which I believe is incorrect and should be called only for home page like `mydomain.com/manifest.json` because that's where my manifest is located (src folder) and other pages should just be treated normally because I believe its causing problems where reloading a subpage causes error and redirects to home page

From looking around it seams setting manifest like

```
"scope": "/",
"start_url": "/",
```

should work but it still calls `mydomain.com/subpage/manifest.json` on subpages and I get error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.` which I read had something to do with the js being read as html or something but idk how that happens or the solution

my index just has

```
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="./manifest.json">
<script async src="./pwacompat.js"></script>
```

Idk if its because manifest is in root and "scope" doesn't limit manifest to only root but rather all subpages included in root too or how this all really works or what is ideal just know its giving me errors but couldn't find and similar questions though there were bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope` does not have any effect on where `manifest.json` is loaded from. It can't since you get into a chicken and egg problem. `manifest.json` is loaded based on your HTML tab. Currently you have the following:

```html
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="./manifest.json">
```

`./manifest.json` says load the `manifest.json` file from the current "directory" `/`, `/subpage/`, or `/subpage/subsubpage/`. Generally you want to always load `manifest.json` from the root of your website with the following HTML tag (without the `.`):

```html
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="/manifest.json">
```